# Подключение postgres к django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

При подключении бд к Django, я так понимаю, выдает много ошибок, которые, я не понимаю как решить. Еще в конце пишет что пользователь не прошел проверку по паролю. Менял его не один раз, ставил и с буквами и без, и даже пустой. Ничего не помогает. При создании миграций или просто при компиляции manage.py выдает следующий код:

```
**root@astra:~/WEB# python  manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 110, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 283, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/root/WEB/environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ВАЖНО:  пользователь "postgres" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)
ВАЖНО:  пользователь "postgres" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)**
```

Comment: Покажите, как вы подключали. Мне код нужен

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME':'diplom',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'12345678',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    }
}

Comment: В поле ENGINE уберите _psycopg2. Попробуй создать новую базу данных

Comment: @Кирилл Попробуй подключиться через pgadmin или psql. Скорее всего действительно пароль не так задал. Каким образом создаешь бд, пользователя и задаешь пароль?